# Retrieving IPV6 address of connections on Apache2 & Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ipv6, apache2, ubuntu-20.04

I'm unable to get IPV6 addresses from connections to my server. All connections display an IPV4 only even when the IPV6 is available.

UFW has apache full and V6 allowed.

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere
Apache Full                ALLOW       Anywhere
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Apache Full (v6)           ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

netstat displays the following:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      995/apache2
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      995/apache2
```

Also my apache conf is set to just `Listen 80` and `Listen 443` and virtual hosts are `*:80` and `*:443` in all relative places.

In theory I should see IPV6 addresses coming in. I must be missing something. Just to clarify the connection is not behind any proxy or cdn or load balancers.

My guess is there is a setting somewhere that is forcing IPv4. But I can't seem to find from where.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have AAAA DNS records for your IPv6 addresses?

Comment: If you test a connection from outside of your server to the IPv6 address of your server, what is the result?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider, I don't beleive we have any records at all setup for IPV6. Will the server need to have an ipv6 address in order to receive IPV6 from people visiting sites etc?

Comment: Of course. And the DNS records as well.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Got a quick question for you, I've jsut ran ifconfig with the grep inet6. It returned 2 ipv6's. Is this normal? If so which one would I pick?

Comment: most probably none of them. Every ipv6 capable device has by default two or more ipv6 addresses which are useless for connection from remote machines. Maybe you should learn how ipv6 works before venturing further.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I'm not sure what you're saying is right that none of them is the correct one to take. I have eth0 and 1 active which I forgot at the time which I use for public and private connections. So it will be the one set for public connections that I use for the dns.

Comment: Well, if you had disclosed the first octet of the addresses or their scope we could yell you more. This way we can't.

Comment: `I should see IPV6 addresses coming in` which addresses? From where?

Comment: IPv6 is not just one address; things have changed. I would suggest [HE.net's IPv6 certification](https://ipv6.he.net/certification/). While it doesn't go *very* deep it teaches you the basics and helps configure the stuff correctly. When your question is if the server needs an IPv6 address to receive IPv6 traffic, there's some pieces of knowledge missing.